# add plugins in vuetify using Vue.use()

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I am using vutify with nuxt

I want to add a product zoom plugin in my vuetify application

https://github.com/akulubala/vue-product-zoomer

They showed in order to use the feature you need to add this following.

```js
import ProductZoomer from 'vue-product-zoomer'
Vue.use(ProductZoomer)
```

where can i find `Vue.use` in my application file in `vuetify`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow this steps:

1. Add `plugins` folder in root directory of your nuxt project.
2. In this directory, create new file called
   `vue-product-zoomer.js`.
3. Add following codes in this file:

```
import Vue from "vue"
import ProductZoomer from 'vue-product-zoomer'
Vue.use(ProductZoomer)
```

4. In `nuxt.config.js` file add following line to `plugins` array:

```
export default {
  // ...

  plugins: [
      ...
      { src: '~/plugins/vue-product-zoomer.js', mode: 'client' },
  ],

  // ...
}
```

After doing above steps, you can access this plugins globally through your nuxt app.

Comment: I used your solution, it shows 500 internal server error when I am loading the app.

Comment: prepend -client to the end of the filename, `vue-product-zoomer-client.js`

Comment: Try this `{ src: '~/plugins/vue-product-zoomer.js', mode: 'client' }` instead of `"~/plugins/vue-product-zoomer.js"` in plugins array.